# android, why library module with minifyEnabled false

Tags: android, proguard

Having a app which uses some libs.
Saw the lib has

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

and the `proguard-rules.pro` has some rules to keep some classes.

My believe is since the R8 is by default on for the shrinking/obfuscation, and the `minifyEnabled false` will disable it.
If that is true, does it mean the lib's aar will be built with no shrinking/obfuscation?

If the app by default with the R8 on, the app will do  shrinking/obfuscation including the depended library?

Comment: do u mean that the library itself has minifyEnabled false in it's own project?

Comment: @MahmoudOmara, yes in the lib's build.gradle it has minifyEnabled false.

Comment: you need to customize ur own app to have the minifyEnabled and proguard rules, just make sure to add the rules that every library u have ever used is in ur own proguard file

Comment: what is the benefits to set minifyEnabled false in the lib?

Comment: there is no benefit, you can't edit the code from the library you are importing unless you copy paste the whole thing and include the source code in your own project

Answer (score 6):

For a library project, `minifyEnabled false` means that the final AAR will not be processed with R8 i.e no code optimizations or dead code removal will be performed.

If an app project has `minifyEnabled true`, R8 will process app code, all external (Maven) libraries, and local library projects, and it will use rules specified in the application to do that.

As a general rule, R8 runs only when the final binary is produced, either AAR or APK or app bundle, and whether it is enabled or not is specified in the project that produces that artifact (library or application project).